# Creating an IR sensor

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, infrared

Is a PIR sensor as easy as just a receiver? Rather than use some pre-canned device I was planning to just hook up an IR LED to my microcontroller and then read the IR sensor/receiver for a threshold voltage level. My concern is that is a naive assumption as everyone would just do that instead of buying these pre-made sensor packages.

Comment: What is it you are trying to sense?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21552/alternate-ways-of-measuring-distance-lateral/21555#21555

Comment: @Majenko well I was actually going for a PIR but that was (unfortunately) not specified in my question. However, the information provided here was very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you propose will work as long as you can keep all other light out of the sensor.  If the sensor is inside some equipment where it will always be dark except your transmitted IR, then you may get away with it.  Even then, varying temperature will add a varying DC offset to your received signal.  AC coupling the signal from the sensor and using a protocol that doesn't depend on the DC level is a good idea.

In most cases though, the ambient light level is unknown but can easily vary be several orders of magnitude during normal operation.  It can also be stronger than the transmitted signal.  The way this is usually dealt with is to make sure the transmitted signal is modulated on a carrier.  The ambient level is close to a DC offset and can then be filtered out.

The common three-terminal IR receivers do several useful things all in one cheap integrated package.  They filter out frequencies outside the IR LED range (usually around 910 nm) that the sensor still responds to, do the amplification, DC rejection, carrier detection, and demodulation.  You supply 5V and ground, and the third pin indicates when it see the presence of IR modulated at the specific frequency for that device.  These devices are available at a range of frequencies in the 30-50 kHz range.  It may take up to 10 carrier cycles for this integrated receiver to indicate the presence of the carrier.

Common consumer devices, like TV remotes, use a protocol above this such that everything is encoded as bursts of carrier of varying lengths and varying gaps between bursts.  The information is carried in the length and sequence of the bursts and spaces.  There are various things that can go wrong with this process, so it's a good idea to send data in packets with a checksum in each packet.  If the direction is one way, then send everything mutliple times because no one packet is guaranteed to be received.

### Now that you say these are PIR sensors:

PIR sensors are quite different from IR photosensors.  Basically, they are at opposite ends of the infrared spectrum.  IR photosensors are sensitive to just below visible light.  910 nm is a common center wavelength, for example.  PIR sensors are meant to detect the black body radiation from something like a human walking around the environment.  They work on a different principle than a photodiode or phototransistor, and are meant to pick up much longer wavelengths.

You have to decide what you are trying to do.  If you want to detect people moving around in a room, then a PIR sensor is appropriate with the right lens or occlusion.  If you want to do digital communication, then a PIR sensor is essentially useless and you want a IR photodiode or phototransistor.  This is what I thought you wanted (since you originally mentioned a emitter) when I wrote the original section of my answer above.

Comment: Hey Olin, while this was awesome info, I actually was looking for a PIR to detect a hand wave in front of the device (think public restroom touch-less faucet switches). Do you have any recommendations for something cheap and pre-canned? Thanks!

Comment: @Nate: You should edit your question to clarify.  Since you mentioned "emitter", it never occurred to me you meant passive IR detector.  The "passive" part basically means receiver only.  As for PIR, the circuit looks for changes in level from a few 100 mHz to a few Hz.  Usually these have special lenses that make multiple vertical stripes of a single object.  That makes it fade in and out as it moves horizontally.  This is a common technology in cheap motion sensors.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what I was talking about! This provides good clarity so I can do some more research.

Comment: I believe the lenses used with PIR based motion sensors are called [Fresnel lenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens)

Comment: Ok, that helps a lot. I made it up in my mind that those devices worked by observing IR splash off the human or something...I have an active imagination! This makes sense so I can narrow my research.

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit you get from a pre-made sensor is the packaging.

The packaging often creates a baffle between the emitter and the detector stopping any bleed over from one to the other.  Without this baffle it can be quite tricky to stop the detector from triggering from the bleed signal whilst still having enough sensitivity to detect the signal you want from the emitter.